# Нужно ли добавлять ID в сущность, если есть артикул и штрихкод?

Tags: база-данных

Вот например у меня в ProductNumber записывается артикул в ручную.
[image: Сущность Product]

Нужно ли добавлять отдельный ID автоинкремент? Я просто увидел в интернете, что кто то делает так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Первичный ключ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Первичный_ключ). Вполне можно использовать _естественный_ ключ, если он сохранит уникальность со временем.

Comment: Теоретически да. Практически... одни считают, что достаточно того, что атрибут обладает свойствами уникальности и отсутствия пустых значений, и он может быть естественным первичным ключом, другие полагают, что пользовательский ввод не может быть идентифицирующим признаком по самОй своей сути, ну хотя бы потому что не допускает валидации с однозначным результатом (возможны ошибки ввода, при которых ошибочное значение распознается как валидное). А потому ответ на этот вопрос находится в области мнений а не аргументов. И не имеет однозначного ответа.

Comment: Я решил использовать суррогатный и естественный ключ вместе. Также я уже потом заметил, что оказывается по моей области артикула может быть не указано, так что суррогатный в любом случае пришлось бы использовать.